# Linking Errors while generating SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, linker

I am trying to generate SDK in that  am using audio related framework ,when compiling code  am getting below linking errors .Any help for solving these issues.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_vDSP_ztoc", referenced from:
      FFTRealCalculator::InverseFFT_A(ComplexSplit*, float*, int) in libEywaSDK.a(FFTRealCalculator.o)
  "_vDSP_ctoz", referenced from:
      FFTRealCalculator::ForwardFFT_A(float const*, unsigned long, ComplexSplit*) in libEywaSDK.a(FFTRealCalculator.o)
  "_vDSP_fft_zrip", referenced from:
      FFTRealCalculator::ForwardFFT_A(float const*, unsigned long, ComplexSplit*) in libEywaSDK.a(FFTRealCalculator.o)
      FFTRealCalculator::InverseFFT_A(ComplexSplit*, float*, int) in libEywaSDK.a(FFTRealCalculator.o)
  "_vDSP_create_fftsetup", referenced from:
      FFTRealCalculator::Initialize(unsigned char) in libEywaSDK.a(FFTRealCalculator.o)
  "_vDSP_destroy_fftsetup", referenced from:
      FFTRealCalculator::~FFTRealCalculator() in libEywaSDK.a(FFTRealCalculator.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 6):

These symbols come from [Accelerate Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html)

I suspect you need to add this to your project.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked so.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to targets -> Valid Architectures & Remove armv7.
- Clean your project & build

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Still I am getting same error after removing armv7, Inplace of armv7 coming different one.

Comment: Set build active architectures to No & try.
Now Which one you are getting ?

Comment: After Setting build active architectures to No , now i am getting Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 and in Valid Architectures only arm64 is available.

Comment: remove arm64 & put armv6

Comment: After removing arm64 and armv6 is added i am getting this error No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7 arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6).        Normally with Valid Architectures armv7,arm64 are working in simulator but when I am trying to run on device  getting 5 errors mentioned above.